# How to use len to figure out how many rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using the variable 'frame' as input, print lines for each row based upon data in the columns

```
frame = {'kind of pet': ['dogs', 'cats', 'gerbils', 'geese'],
 'number of pets': [10, 20, 5, 4]}
```

I expect the output looks like

> dog 10 
>   cats 20 
>   gerbils 5 
>   geese 4

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
for a,b, in zip(frame['kind of pet'],frame['number of pets']):
print("{} {}".format(b,a))
```

Use f strings on python 3.x + for legibility

Comment: Thank u, this works. But is there any way using len?

Comment: Sure:

for i in range(len(frame['kind of pet'])):
    print("{} {}".format(frame['kind of pet'][i],frame['number of pets'][i]))

Not particularly pretty though